# Trigonometric Circle

Tags: trigonometry

I have trouble with this questions,

I don't get it, how can I express the letter with the angle, is it with the functions? 
[image: Circle]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what they mean exactly by "the trigonometric ratios of $\theta$."  But I can tell you that, since the radius has length 1, according to the figure, that $a=\sin\theta$, $d=\cos\theta$, and I'll let you take the rest from there.  I wouldn't generally give that much info for what is obviously a homework problem, but it seems to me that the question is put poorly.

Comment: Thanks @bob.sacamento Indeed, this way of asking troubled me...